# Leaflet.js - Using custom map server

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I've been trying to embed a custom map, of which the tiles are hosted on my local server and is rendered by Leaflet.js. However, I'm having some difficulty in displaying the map on my html page. Here is the screenshot: [image]

this is a "supposed" picture of my country Philippines on zoom 10 but was displayed like that. Also, the map tiles are generated using Maperitive. Hope anyone can help me here. This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>Offline Map Example</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#document").ready(function() {
    var map = L.map('map', {
        minZoom: 10,
        maxZoom: 14,
        zoom: 10,
        center: [11.5326,122.7457]
    });

    L.tileLayer('http://localhost/Tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a     href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    }).addTo(map);

    var southWest = L.LatLng(4.22816513512253, 116.389103446625),
    northEast = L.LatLng(21.6156671213737, 126.979526808346),
    bounds = L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
    map.setMaxBounds(bounds); 

}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="map" name="map" style="height: 440px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Many thanks guys :)

Comment: What does your browser javascript console say ?

Comment: @FranceImage, no error on the console

Comment: Could you check if it's picking the right tile for each position? Check this for reference http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

Comment: Could you put this example live somewhere for us to check? Dropbox should suffice if it's only js

Comment: @sabas, yes i can upload some images for zoom 10 on Dropbox as well as the html code and leaflet js.

Comment: here is the link for dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xqnqcjuyatcjnrg/CustomMap.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included Leaflet's CSS. You need to, and when you do, this will work.